# How to apply a formula in each row using ArrayFormula (maybe?) in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I need to do a sheet to managing some informations in my job.

I'd like to make a compilation of informations filtred by month, i.e., I'd like to insert a month (B1 cell) and all the informations would be refreshed by this month.

For while I could manage this data:

Team (Equipe);
Modules (Módulos); and
Type (Tipo).

and my formula is working:

`=COUNTIFS(Geral!$B$2:$B$45;$A5;Geral!$C$2:$C$45;$B5;Geral!$E$2:$E$45;C$4)`.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(Geral!$B$2:$B$45;$A5;Geral!$C$2:$C$45;$B5;Geral!$E$2:$E$45;C$4;Geral!$F$2:$F$45;MONTH(B1)).
```

I know this formula is wrong, but I don't know how to do this... I've already tried to use arrayformula, but it didn't work...

How do I do this?

Here is the link to the sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NOkvkJ7B3lGcSaUTtUdrnbmdd8AjiRvniH2lM3kASSU/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need is:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(Geral!$B$2:$B$45;$A5;Geral!$C$2:$C$45;$B5;Geral!$E$2:$E$45;C$4;MONTH(Geral!$F$2:$F$45);B1))`

... but beware that date functions in Sheets will read a blank cell as 30/12/1899, therefore MONTH() on a blank cell will return 12. So you might want to include a test to rule out blank-ness:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(Geral!$B$2:$B$45;$A5;Geral!$C$2:$C$45;$B5;Geral!$E$2:$E$45;C$4;MONTH(Geral!$F$2:$F$45);B1;Geral!$F$2:$F$45;"<>"))`

Comment: It worked like a charm, @AdamL! I just added the '$' in your formula (to reference cell B1). Thank's a lot!

Comment: I'd like to improve my data filter: instead of use just one month, I'd like to use how many I want (1 to 12). I created fields with the months names to select with 'x' all of I want to... How can I do this? Could you help me again?

Comment: I don't see extra fields created, but assuming that you could list up to five month numbers in B1:F1, try: `=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(Geral!$B$2:$B$45;$A5;Geral!$C$2:$C$45;$B5;Geral!$E$2:$E$45;C$4;MATCH(MONTH(Geral!$F$2:$F$45);$B$1:$F$1;0);">0";Geral!$F$2:$F$45;"<>"))`